# PHP SimpleTest browser with Javascript disabled

Tags: php, simpletest

I'm trying to add a test using SimpleTest browser to test JavaScript disabled scenario in PHP page.

http://simpletest.org/en/browser_documentation.html

Not sure if it is possible to disable javascript in simpletest browser? Are there any alternatives for this? Thanks

Comment: if your running js disable in 2018, you should leave the internet

Comment: How can PHP catch js status? Some paranoic people using tor browser to prevent executing js on pages.